# Integrate OpenIDConnect into Classic ASP app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have a legacy application built in Classic ASP that needs to access an API - this API is "protected" by an IdentityServer - so basically we need to implement OpenIdConnect support for this legacy application.

By far the easiest solution I can think of is trying to wrap this site somehow in a more updated version, then we could just add a few lines of code in the Owin-startup and everything *should*(?) be fine by adding:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ClientId = "mvc";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.Scope.Add("api1");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
});
```

So it is possible to somehow get OWIN to work with Classic ASP? Or are we doomed to try and built our own client/middleware?

Comment: Did you find a solid solution to this problem? We're also not on OWIN yet, so looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no other "show-stopper" preventing you to update to .Net Framework 4.5.1+, than this is your right solution.

If you go to the [Owin official NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin/) it will show you, that the library particularly has no dependencies, **BUT** this is not quite correct.

If we go to the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin/Microsoft.Owin.csproj) of the Microsoft.Owin we will see:

```
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

So it actually depends on .Net Framework 4.5.1. If you have the possibility to upgrade your project - do it.

Comment: there is a show-stopper! Our org is not ready to move on to asp.net or asp.net core for those apps. I am still looking into how to implement identity server in classic asp pages.